# How to put a value in dropdown using records from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to put a value from database because my dropdown already have a value the same as the text so I want a separate or different value from my text. Example code = 1, text = pathologist.

My controller:

```
public ActionResult MainHistopathologyForm(string id)
{
    var patientprofileViewModel = new MDHPIStables();
    patientprofileViewModel.histopathology = db.histopathology.Find(id);
    patientprofileViewModel.roles = db.roles.Find(Session["role"]);
    var PathologistList = new List<string>();

    var PathologistQry = from d in db.pathologist
                   select d.pathologist;

    PathologistList.AddRange(PathologistQry.Distinct());
    TempData["pathologistlist"] = new SelectList(PathologistList);

    return View(patientprofileViewModel);
}
```

MainHistopathologyForm.cshtml:

```
@Html.Partial("RolesHistopathologyForm", Model.roles, new ViewDataDictionary())


@Html.Partial("Partial_HistopathologyForm", Model.histopathology,
 new ViewDataDictionary())
```

Partial_HistopathologyForm:

```
@{
    ViewBag.concurring1 = TempData["pathologistlist"];
 }                            
@Html.DropDownList("concurring1", "Select Pathologist")
```

Comment: your list which is to be populated should be the second parameter of `DropDownListFor` method

Comment: I cant get it. My first parameter is for the value of the ViewBag.concurring1

Answer (score 0):

@Html.DropDownList("Your ViewBag Name", null, "Select List", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })

Comment: how can I use viewbag without affecting the name of dropdown